# AngularJS Counting Number of Specific Items Starting With a Value in JSON Dataset

Tags: json, angularjs, foreach, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a set of JSON data:

```
"MyMessages": [
        {
            "Code" :  "N101",
            "ID" : "History",
            "Indicator" : "Down",
            "PosChangeMessage" : "test test test test",
            "NegReasonMessage" : "test test test test",
            "Image" : "ImageType.Warning"
        },

        {
            "Code" :  "P874",
            "ID" : "History",
            "Indicator" : "Up",
            "NegReasonMessage" : "test test test test",
            "Image" : "ImageType.Ok"
        },

        {
            "Code" :  "N85",
            "ID" : "Age",
            "Indicator" : "Down",
            "PosChangeMessage" : "test test test test",
            "Image" : "ImageType.Warning"
        },

        {
            "Code" :  "N846",
            "ID" : "Products",
            "Indicator" : "Up",
            "PosChangeMessage" : "test test test test",
            "Image" : "ImageType.Ok"
        },
    ],
```

I can display how many items there are in MyMessages via `{{ MyMessages.length }}`

However what i want to know is how many `Code` items there starting with P and N.

So, in the example above:

P = 1

N = 3

I can count how many `Code` elements there are via:

```
angular.forEach(MyMessages, function(message){

   if(message.Code){
       $scope.Number++;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (message.Code[0] === "p") return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the "filter" method on the array itself:

```
var num_code_elements_p = MyMessages.filter(function(item) { 
                              return item.Code.charAt(0) == 'P' ;
                          }).length
var num_code_elements_n = MyMessages.filter(function(item) { 
                              return item.Code.charAt(0) == 'N' ;
                          }).length
```